# In which tightest class does the groupoid $(\mathbb{Z}^{+},lcm)$ belong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let be the following classes of the groupoids/magmas: groupoid$\ \supset\\$ semigroup$\ \supset\\$ monoid$\ \supset\\$ group$\ \supset\\$ Abelian group.

Comment: I think that this is associative, so it is surely a semigroup

Comment: and it also has an identity element so it is a monoid